# How to create a base ViewController class that has a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have several View Controllers, all using a UITableView, with identical custom cells. The UITableView Datasource methods are identical too (to the line); all that changes is the data source itself (the array from which the table view is loaded). It seems rather redundant for me to have to copy the exact same code for 5 such View Controllers (not to mention it's a bad coding practice!).

I therefore thought of creating a base (or parent) view controller that extends UIViewController, and have all my following (child) controllers inherit from this base view controller.

My problem is this: My base view controller needs to have a UITableView property, and it also contains the DataSource methods. I cannot get the UITableViews within the child view controllers to refer to the parent class for their DataSource.

Am I on a completely wrong track? Is there a better approach to this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have one controller into which you add a property for the data source.

When you segue to the controller or create it set the data source property.

If all the code is identical except the data source array, you only need one controller.

In xcode add a new source file: e.g. `MyDataViewerController` which inherits `UITableViewController`.

In that file when created, add a property of the form:

```
@property NSArray *dataSource;
```

Click on one of your view controllers in storyboard and click the Class attribute inspector tab. Set the class to `MyDataViewerController`.

You can now use this controller to show any of your data. You can probably delete all the others.

I've assumed its an array containing the data. Replace this with whatever you use.

Assuming you segue to this controller from somewhere, set the property in the 
`prepareForSegue` function.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot believe I overlooked this; I've done it loads of times before. I used a 3rd party library for transitioning into these views rather than the usual segues, which is probably why I overlooked it. Thanks again!